# How to render a UIView to a UIImage Faster

Tags: swift, uiimage, uigraphicscontext, uigraphicsrenderer

I'm trying to render a UIView (with subviews) into a UIImage.

I'm using the new iOS 10+ `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` as seen below

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
let image = renderer.image { ctx in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

But my question is how can I do this faster? I'm trying to render this UIImage before I push a new UIViewController and it has a **super long delay until the UIImage is finished processing**. I think this is because the renderer `UIGraphicsImageRendererContext` is being created for every instantiation.

Is there any way to preload the context in the background before it needs to be used to render the image?

Or am I thinking about optimizing this wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you call the code you added in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: No I do this before pushing to a new viewcontroller. I'm rendering a UIView that has filters and other effects applied to it so I have to wait until the user is finished before I can run this code